# Please help to explain a case of Scala constructor and companion object

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I think that I would make some mistakes in below explanation for my question
but within my limit understanding I cannot figure out how to correctly describe the issue

The scala code snipet as below:

```
sealed trait List[+A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
object List {
  def apply[A](as: A*):List[A] =
    if (as.isEmpty) Nil
    else Cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
}
```

If I create object x as:
val x = List(1,2,3)

I pass into companion object "List", three numbers as : 1 ,2 and 3
Then, internally, function apply is triggered
At the moment of construction, how could these three numbers has method/attribute like: as.head and as.tail

I guess it could be possibly a kind of pattern matching, but even that, I could not understand the magic that number "as" now has method/attribute for ".head" and ".tail"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in the REPL.

```
scala> def apply[A](as :A*) = as
apply: [A](as: A*)Seq[A]
```

So the compiler considers the varargs variable, `as`, to be of type `Seq[A]`, which is where the `.head` and `.tail` comes from.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that `as: A*` is a variable argument what is converted to an array-like object, actually a `WrappedArray$ofInt` in your case.
[`WrappedArray`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/collection/mutable/WrappedArray.html) has `head` and `tail` methods.

You can extend your definition of `List` object to see `A*`'s class like this:

```
object List {
  def apply[A](as: A*):List[A] = {
    println(as.getClass)    
    if (as.isEmpty) Nil
    else Cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
  }
}
```

For a more detailed explanation check e.g. [this](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-define-methods-variable-arguments-varargs-fields) .

Comment: [There is nothing in the Scala Language Specification that says anything about a repeated parameter being represented as a `WrappedArray`](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#repeated-parameters). All the spec guarantees is that it is a `Seq`. Please, do not, under any circumstances, make any assumption about the type of `as` other than `Seq`.